# Flutter generating list with FOR loop via GET method

Tags: flutter

Good morning. I am building simple workout app in Flutter. I want to generate list of custom class Excersise:

```
class Excersise{
   int id;
   String name;
   int duration;
   int type;

  Excersise({
  required this.id,
  required this.duration,
  required this.name,
  required this.type,
});
```

I want to pass parameter rounds, wtime(workout time) and ctime(cooldown time) from parent widget and then my app should create list of excersises. It should be pairs of workout and cool down time like this: wo 30sec, cd 15sec, wo 30sec, cd 15sec and so one (based on rounds value). I tried to generate this list via GET but after building this widget i get Stack overflow error. Maybe there is some error in code, maybe this is completely wrong method. Here is a code and thank for your advices.

```
class QuickWorkoutList extends StatelessWidget {
  final int rounds;
  final int wtime;
  final int ctime;

  QuickWorkoutList({
    required this.rounds,
    required this.wtime,
    required this.ctime,
  });

  List<Excersise> get _qList {
    var newEx = Excersise(id: 0, duration: 0, name: '', type: 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < rounds * 2; i++) {
      if (i.isEven) {
        newEx.id = i;
        newEx.name = 'Workout';
        newEx.type = 0;
        newEx.duration = wtime;
      } else {
        newEx.id = i;
        newEx.name = 'Cooldown';
        newEx.type = 1;
        newEx.duration = ctime;
      }
      _qList.add(newEx);
    }
        throw 'No data';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getter method `_qList` is wrong implemented. You should create an empty `List<Excersise>` and add the `Workout` and `Cooldown` there. Currently you are recursively calling your `_qList` which has no anchor to stop. Consequently you have an endless loop. Btw I think you mean `Exercise` instead of `Excersise`.

```
List<Exercise> get _qList {
    // All exercises stored
    final List<Exercise> exercises = [];
    
    // Exercise properties
    int duration;
    String name;
    int type;

    for (int i = 0; i < rounds * 2; i++) {
      // Get exercise properties depending on id
      if (i.isEven) {
        name = 'Workout';
        type = 0;
        duration = wtime;
      } else {
        name = 'Cooldown';
        type = 1;
        duration = ctime;
      }

      // Add new exercise to list
      exercises.add(
        Excersise(
          id: i,
          duration: duration,
          name: name,
          type: type,
        ),
      );
    }
    return exercises;
  }
```

Comment: Can you uppvote/accept the answer, so that others know that the question has been answered?

Comment: I tried but I need at least 15 reputation to do this, I've created account today. :/

Comment: I guess at least two users have to upvote my question to earn 2*10 reputation points to enable me to cast upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call add on your _qList getter, and that creates stack overflow I guess. You should use new List and return it from your _qList getter like this:

```
    List<Excersise> get _qList {
    var newEx = Excersise(id: 0, duration: 0, name: '', type: 0);
    List<Excersise> exercises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rounds * 2; i++) {
      if (i.isEven) {
        newEx.id = i;
        newEx.name = 'Workout';
        newEx.type = 0;
        newEx.duration = wtime;
      } else {
        newEx.id = i;
        newEx.name = 'Cooldown';
        newEx.type = 1;
        newEx.duration = ctime;
      }
      exercises.add(newEx);
    }
    return exercises;
  }
```

Comment: This will throw an error since you never initialized `exercises` .

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it in hurry, thanks for pointing that out. It's fixed now.